# Redirect before rewrite

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

Had an issue where I need to redirect old URLs, but not disable the mod_rewrite for page structure.

```
redirect 301 /home.html http://www.example.com/
```

It needs to live on the Symphony 2.0 .htaccess file

```
### Symphony 2.0.x ###
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteBase /

 ### DO NOT APPLY RULES WHEN REQUESTING "favicon.ico"
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} favicon.ico [NC]
 RewriteRule .* - [S=14]

 ### IMAGE RULES 
 RewriteRule ^image\/(.+\.(jpg|gif|jpeg|png|bmp))$ extensions/jit_image_manipulation/lib/image.php?param=$1 [L,NC]

 ### CHECK FOR TRAILING SLASH - Will ignore files
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

 ### ADMIN REWRITE
 RewriteRule ^symphony\/?$ index.php?mode=administration&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteRule ^symphony(\/(.*\/?))?$ index.php?symphony-page=$1&mode=administration&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

 ### FRONTEND REWRITE - Will ignore files and folders
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*\/?)$ index.php?symphony-page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>
######
```

Answer (score 2):

*Try this code in your .htaccess file:*

- `RewriteRule ^home(.*) http://example.com/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: The important point here is that you've changed the mod_alias `Redirect` to a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` to perform the redirect. Different modules execute at different times (and it can even vary from server to server). By default mod_rewrite will execute _before_ mod_alias, regardless of their apparent order, so it's quite possible that your original `Redirect` is simply being _skipped_. It is recommended to never mix redirects from both modules, because of this "unpredictable" behaviour. (In addition... the `(.*)` at the end of the `RewriteRule` pattern is not required here.)